# Expected number of offspring with immedate vs. delayed selection

Tags: probability

Say there's one green dot to start. Every "generation" each green dot has two offspring dots (and itself dies). After 20 such generations there will be 1,048,576 green dots.

Now suppose that when one green dot goes through one generation to become two green dots, there's a 1/100 chance that either offspring dot is red. So the odds of the following outcomes are:

Two green dots: (99/100)*(99/100)

One green dot, one red dot: 2*(99/100)*(1/100)

Two red dots: (1/100)*(1/100)

Once a dot is red, it only gives birth to red dots.

After 20 generations, what's the expected number of green dots? I think that it's the total number of dots, 1,048,576, times the chance that a dot anywhere in the family history turned red, so 1,048,576 * (1 - 1/100)^20. Right?

Now here's my real question. Suppose that in the process described above, turning into a red dot is replaced by immediate death. So the probabilities for offspring are now:

Two green dots: (99/100)*(99/100)

One green dot: 2*(99/100)*(1/100)

No offspring: (1/100)*(1/100)

Is the expected number of green dots the same as in the green/red scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario where the red dot immediately dies will produce just as many green dots as one where the red dots stays alive but only produces more red dots, since in either case you are getting 0 more green dots as a result of that initial red dot.